# Android App crashes as Json element is empty String ("") and not Object

Tags: android, json, gson

I am working on an android project and using RxAndroid, Retrofit to make API call and retrieve json. The json looks something like following :

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "parent": "jhasj",
            "u_deviation": "skasks",
            "caused_by": "ksks",
            "u_owner_mi": {
                "link": "https://gddhdd.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/sys_user/ghtytu",
                "value": "ghtytu"
            },
            "impact": "",  
}
]
}
```

I am using gson to parse the Json. The problem is "u_owner_mi" sometimes reruns empty string "" when there is no value assigned to it. I don't have access to change the return type to null. This is making my app crash as I am expecting an object here. 
I get the following error :
**Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING**

Answer (score 1):

If you can't modify the server, try replacing the offending line in the server response before passing it to the Gson parser. Something like:

```
String safeResponse = serverResponse.replace("\"u_owner_mi\": \"\"", "\"u_owner_mi\": null");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app (client) code is expecting an object according to a contract specified in the class that you pass to GSON. Your app behaves as it should and crashes loudly. You should consider having your server return `"u_owner_mi" : null` instead of an empty string, assuming you have control over that. The `u_owner_mi` field on the client side would have to be a *nullable* type.

If you don't have the ability to fix the api, you could also write a custom deserializer.

Suppose your result class and sub-object are:

```
data class Result(
    val parent: String,
    val owner: Any?
)

data class Owner(
    val link: String,
    val value: String
)
```

The deserializer could be:

```
class ResultDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<Result> {
    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type?, context: JsonDeserializationContext?): Result {
        val jsonObject = json.asJsonObject
        val ownerProperty = jsonObject.get("owner")
        return Result(
            parent = jsonObject.get("parent").asString,
            owner = if (ownerProperty.isJsonObject) context?.deserialize<Owner>(ownerProperty.asJsonObject, Owner::class.java)
                    else ownerProperty.asString
        )
    }
}
```

Finally, to add the deserializer:

```
    @Test
    fun deserialization() {
        val gson = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Result::class.java, ResultDeserializer()).create()
        val result1 = gson.fromJson<Result>(jsonWithObject, Result::class.java)
        val result2 = gson.fromJson<Result>(jsonWithEmpty, Result::class.java)
    }
```

Comment: I dont have control over the server. I am trying to fetch data from ServiceNow. Is there a way I can handle such responses in the code ?

Comment: Yes you could also create a custom deserializer.